# Renaming a project in Xcode, I cannot rename anymore and it crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I tried to rename my project in `xcode`, but when I tried to go to a second view controller, everything crashed. So, I tried to rename it one more time. But now I am really stuck...

It is now saying that it is running `'myNewName.temp_caseinsensitive_rename'` on `iPhone` and still everything crashes when I go to the second view controller. But now, I cannot change it. Everytime I change it, the '.temp_caseinsensitive_rename' is still there... Crap, What should I do! I am really lost now...

I am using `xcode 6.2` on `Mavericks`.

EDIT
I have come a little further. My app works now, but everything is mixed with the name. The **project name** is now *MyNewName*, inside build settings the **product name** is '*myOldName*' and during compiling I still see some names with the '.temp_caseinsensitive_rename'. What to do? I simply want to change the name of the app, it is so hard now.

Comment: "I simply want to change the name of the app" Then why did you change the name of the _project_? They have nothing to do with each other. The project is something _you_ see while developing. The app is something the user sees on the device (or in iTunes). They are unrelated to each other.

Comment: So, how could I rename only the name of the project? It has now gone so wrong, that I am redoing it in a new project :( So I would really like to know how to rename the name of the app only. I reported this problem to apple, because this doesn't sound good to me.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the app as shown below the icon on the device is the `CFBundleDisplayName` setting (Bundle Display Name) in the *Info.plist*. That's all you need to change. Leave the project name alone; changing it can break things (as you have discovered) and there is no reason to do so, since it has nothing to do with anything the user ever sees.

The name of the app that users will see in the App Store is different yet again; that is something you will set manually in your browser at iTunes Connect when you submit the app.

Comment: This is so helpful because changing the project can just break everything.